# PHP: Check if it has been one week since timestamp

Tags: php

Let's assume:

```
$time = '2010-05-17 02:49:30' // (retrieved from MySQL TIMESTAMP field)
```

How do I do the following in PHP:

1) Check if it has been more than one week since this time has passed?

2) Assuming "false" on (1), find out how much more time until the one week mark, rounded to days and hours remaining.

I know this is pretty straightforward, but it uses a very specific syntax. Having never played with time calculations before, I'd appreciate some guidance.

Thanks!

Comment: why not to use mysql for such calculations?

Comment: Ah - wouldn't mind doing that. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - That's just terrible advice and whoever upvoted you needs their head checked. See my answer.

Comment: @Coronatus ok ok I agree. just show me the way to filter a week old records to use instead of this terrible way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$time = strtotime('2010-05-10 02:49:30');
$one_week_ago = strtotime('-1 week');

if( $time > $one_week_ago ) { 
    // it's sooner than one week ago
    $time_left = $time - $one_week_ago;
    $days_left = floor($time_left / 86400); // 86400 = seconds per day
    $hours_left = floor(($time_left - $days_left * 86400) / 3600); // 3600 = seconds per hour
    echo "Still $days_left day(s), $hours_left hour(s) to go.";
}
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks. Basically same to what Coronatus supplied, but more fleshed out.

Comment: I would be curious on the time difference between UNIX_TIMESTAMP() in MySQL and strtotime() in PHP on a large dataset.

Answer (score 6):

Doesn't [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) let you do things like this...

```
$timestamp = strtotime($time);
$oneweekago = strtotime("-1 week");
if($oneweekago<=$timestamp) {
    // it's been less than one week
    $secondsleft = $oneweekago - $timestamp;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use strptime/strftime (or mysql TIMESTAMP) to parse your time and then check if it is at least one week form the present (one week = 604800 seconds).

If one week has not passed then you can work out how many seconds still remain from which you can calculate days and hours left.

Comment: Good approach - didn't think to boil it down that way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM 'contents'
WHERE (WEEK(NOW(), 7) = WEEK('publish_up', 7)) AND YEAR('publish_up') = YEAR(NOW())
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of great functions for date manipulation.  Take a look at this page in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php

Answer (score 0):

mysql has a [bunch of datetime functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html). date_add and datediff among them.
though to count hours could be tricky.
Anyway I can't believe you going to do that comparison using PHP

Answer (score -3):

Here you are:

```
$time = strtotime('2010-05-9 02:49:30');
$oneWeekAgo = time() - (7 * 84600);

$hasOneWeekPassed = $time < $oneWeekAgo;
if (!$hasOneWeekPassed)
{
    $timeLeft = $time - $oneWeekAgo;
}

var_dump($hasOneWeekPassed);
var_dump($timeLeft);
```

Absolutely do NOT do what Col. Shrapnel said (calculate it in MySQL). Not only is it completely unnecessary but that will be at least 20 times slower than the pure PHP above.

Comment: whoa. got proof? what if I gonna filter records out from a big table? should I not use mysql too?

Comment: why should it be slower in mysql? if he is querying from the database, he can easily select an additional boolean field `DATE_ADD(my_timestamp, ONE_WEEK) < NOW() AS older_than_one_week` (can't remember the exact syntax now). this seems more sane than mixing two languages